# React MUI datepicker gives me a datetime not a date

Tags: reactjs, datetime, material-ui, datepicker

Even though I have initialized the format as a prop in DesktopDatePicker, when I change the value it comes like this: `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

```
   <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DesktopDatePicker
                  inputVariant="outlined"
                  id="date-picker-dialog"
                  label="Birthday"
                  fullWidth
                  name="dob"
                  onChange={(val) => {
                    formik.setFieldValue("dob", val);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                  value={formik.values.dob}
                  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                  error={formik.errors.dob && formik.touched.dob}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: `DatePicker` `onChange` return value in Date type like `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.
You can convert it to any format with `Get Date Methods`: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp .
or using library like `moment js`: https://momentjs.com/